# How to access an array of structs in simulink?

Tags: matlab, dll, struct, simulink

I have the problem, that I have to access a funktion form a dll in matlab/Simulink in the rtw.
This should work with a s function, but I have the needed parameters in a array of structures organized.

The question is now how I can reach them when I want to call my DLL function?

Or is there a better way (e.g. level 2 Matlab files or something similar)?
The pure simulation (without RTW) worked pretty well with level 2 m files but I am not able to write a tlc file for compiling them. I did not find much on the net and the documentation only about C sources.

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I coded the problem in C and used an array where I defined to order of the elements. Then I wrote some interface functions to access this "virtual" struct.

This is not very good coding but the easiest way I have found and it is portable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For signals in Simulink, what you are asking for is an [array of buses](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/bsocrb0.html).  There is similar support for using arrays of structs for parameters.  For calling an external function, you might want to look at the [legacy code tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/bq4g1es-1.html).  You might also be able to use the [MATLAB function block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f6-6010.html) to call your external dll.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @MikeT says:

Generating code from Level 2 M-S-Functions is problematic. Read this: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/f7-67622.html#brgscav-1

Also, M-S-functions are generally slow, because they run in the MATLAB interpreter: http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2010/10/28/tips-for-simulation-performance/